# How might I align the result of the sum of the following figure as represented in the second figure?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

[image]

(2)-figure is represented as follows;

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
using the detached coefficients, we have the scheme\\\\
\noindent
$\begin{array}{@{} >{{}}r @{} >{{}}r *{20}{ @{}>{{}}r<{{}}@{} } }
& 1 & + & _nC_{1} & + & _nC_{2} & + & _nC_{3} & + & \dotsb  & + & _nC_{n-1} & + & _nC_{n} \\
\times \\
& 1 & + &  1      & \\
\midrule
& 1 &   &         & + & _nC_{1} &   &         & + & _nC_{2} &   &   &   &   &   &   &         & + & _nC_{n} \\
&   &   &         & + &  1      &   &         & + & _nC_{1} &   &   &   &   &   &   &      & + & _nC_{n-1} & + & _nC_{n} \\
\midrule
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: It looks to me that the first two lines and the bottom line are normal expressions and the two intermediate lines are aligned by hand (badly).